# trying to install pyenv on 22.04 -- missing python-openssl?

Tags: openssl, pipenv, pyenv, ubuntu-22.04

E: Unable to locate package python-openssl

Have a fresh install of 22.04 (non-upgrade) and seems I'm running into a ton of issues trying to make my "usual" tools work with Python 3.10.4 that comes bundled with. It's too scary trying to downgrade a bundled Python, much rather use dev tools like venv or pipenv.

[RealPython](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv/#virtual-environments-and-pyenv) article here says I need to install these build tools, get that (still not sure pipenv will run correctly), but it chokes on openssl. Any reason that is happening? Seems like I ran into an issue with that module earlier on in the 22.04 world but can't recollect exactly where.

The more of this type of issue I run into, the more I question the Ubuntu packagers going with 3.10, I'm sure I could check to see how soon these issues will be resolved on pypi.org or the like, but curious how many of my fellow devs feel like they upgraded the base OS too soon?

Comment: Looks like python-openssl was dropped as of 22.04. Okay, the article in RP was prob written before that. Still looks like lots of headwinds with a bundled Python version and lack of adequate use cases/testing before release of 22.04. I will wait till they're all resolved, and expect a few hiccups from an LTS release that will be around a few years.

Comment: +1 with the same problem, I really need pyenv. After many hours trying everything I found about this issue I'm considering remove the 22.04 partition and stick to Ubuntu 20.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/2293 ?

Comment: This looked promising at first ... but 2 differences: 1)on Mac not Linux, at least I've never heard of brew for Linux; and, 2)his *base* python was 3.8.9 not 3.10.x. So no, guess the issue is not quite resolved for Linux/Ubuntu 22.04 without ripping out the hermetically-sealed 3.10.4

Answer (score 10):

I got pyenv working on Ubuntu 22.04 (the WSL2 version of 22.04, but still) by installing python3-openssl instead of just python-openssl.  Like, by using

sudo apt install python3-openssl

Comment: I wonder why is python still being used as python3 when the usage of python2 is basically next to none by now. Anyway, thanks for this - it worked.